# Div sections that appear from right to left

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to achieve this:

[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00SU2.png)

I have divs with ids ="section1", "section2", etc. this divs contain part of a form with some questions :) within each div, we have another div playing the roll of button.

I have done a javascript code that when you click the "button" then the  will move from right: auto, to right:100%; and section2 will move from right:-100% to right: auto; in other words, section2 goes from right border to the center and actual section goes from center to the very left and vanish. More like a carousell? I'm doing it manually but is a pain and I would like to understand how to automatize this? can someone explain me? thanks

```js
document.getElementById('section2').onclick = function() {
  $('.one').css('right', '100%');
  $('.two').css('right', 'auto');
}

document.getElementById('section3').onclick = function() {
  $('.two').css('right', '100%');
  $('.three').css('right', 'auto');
}
```

```css
.questionsContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 200px);
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lime;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.section {
  background-color: purple;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.one {
  position: absolute;
  right: auto;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.two {
  position: absolute;
  right: -100%;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.three {
  position: absolute;
  right: -100%;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.sectionTitle {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.buttonContinue {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 20px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="questionsContainer">

  <div class="section one">
    <p class="sectionTitle">This is the First Question?</p>
    <div class="buttonContinue" id="section2">CONTINUE</div>
  </div>

  <div class="section two">
    <p class="sectionTitle">Aja! time for the Second one!!</p>
    <div class="buttonContinue" id="section3">CONTINUE</div>
  </div>

  <div class="section three">
    <p class="sectionTitle">Another Question? 3 so far?</p>
    <div class="buttonContinue" id="section4">CONTINUE</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

oh I'm trying to animate it smoothly with transition: all 0.2s ease; and it doesn't work, it simply appears in the middle:(, I want to make a smooth transition?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try a JS plugin like this one http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples

Answer (score 0):

animate the section tags from 0 to 100% since animation from auto to 100% will not work. I have re-aligned the section tags to 100% so as to animate from 0 to 100%.

https://jsfiddle.net/yh4yvoe3/11/

```js
document.getElementById('section2').onclick = function(){
$('.one').css('right','100%');
$('.two').css('right','0');
}   

document.getElementById('section3').onclick = function(){
$('.two').css('right','100%');
$('.three').css('right','0');
}
```

```css
.questionsContainer {
        width: 100%;
        height: calc(100% - 200px);
        position: absolute;
        background-color: lime;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

.section {
       
        transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
.section >div {
    width: fit-content;
    background-color: purple;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 5px;
}
    .one {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    }

    .two {
        position: absolute;
        right: -100%;
        transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    }

    .three {
        position: absolute;
        right: -100%;
        transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    }

    .sectionTitle {
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        color: white;
        font-size: 30px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .buttonContinue {
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        color: white;
        font-size: 16px;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        background-color: red;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin: 20px auto;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 100px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="questionsContainer">

        <div class="section one">
            <div>
            <p class="sectionTitle">This is the First Question?</p>
            <div class="buttonContinue" id="section2">CONTINUE</div>            
            </div>        
        </div>

        <div class="section two">
            <div>
            <p class="sectionTitle">Aja! time for the Second one!!</p>
            <div class="buttonContinue" id="section3">CONTINUE</div>            
            </div>        
        </div>

        <div class="section three">
            <div>
             <p class="sectionTitle">Another Question? 3 so far?</p>
            <div class="buttonContinue" id="section4">CONTINUE</div>           
            </div>        
        </div>

    </div>
```